# Динамически создать сборку с файлом ресурсов

Tags: c#, .net, clr

Задача: создать сборку на лету с файлом ресурсов внутри.

Пробую такой вариант:

```
        private class InProcessCompiler
        {
            private string sourceCode = @"
    using System;
    namespace Bar {
        public class Test { }
        }
        ";
        public Assembly BuildAssembyWithResources(string resource)
        {
            CompilerParameters cp = new CompilerParameters()
            {
                GenerateInMemory = false,
                OutputAssembly = "test.dll",
                CoreAssemblyFileName = "test.dll",
                GenerateExecutable = false,
                CompilerOptions = "/out:C:\\"
            };

            cp.EmbeddedResources.Add(resource);

            // Hard-code parameters for test.
            var po = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "CompilerVersion", "v4.0" } 
            };

            var p = new CSharpCodeProvider(po);

            var ass = p.CompileAssemblyFromSource(cp, sourceCode);

            return ass.CompiledAssembly;

            //return Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        }
    }
```

Но при обращению с свойству `CompiledAssembly` происходить ексепшин: `((System.IO.FileNotFoundException)(ass.CompiledAssembly))._fusionLog`

Вот полный лог:

```
=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: Where-ref bind. Location = D:\...Tests\bin\Debug\test.dll
LOG: Appbase = file:///D:/...Tests/bin/Debug/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in LoadFrom load context.
WRN: Native image will not be probed in LoadFrom context. Native image will only be probed in default load context, like with Assembly.Load().
LOG: No application configuration file found.
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: The same bind was seen before, and was failed with hr = 0x80070002.
```

Подскажите в чем проблема или чего не хватает, пожалуйста.

[image: Свойство Errors]

Comment: Метод `CodeDomProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource` возвращает `CompilerResults`, у которого есть свойство `Errors`. Посмотрите что в нем.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, обновил вопрос, что то пока внятной информации по `CS2032` не нашел

Comment: @AntonKomyshan: А если убрать ресурсы, то всё работает?

Comment: @VladD, да, проблема была в ресурсах.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема решилась следующим образом:

Сначала пришлось записать ресурсы в файл, а потом передать путь к файлу в метод `BuildAssembyWithResources`. Судя по всему `EmbeddedResources.Add` и ожидал не строку ресурсов, а путь к ресурсу. Вот так вот банально...

Comment: Перед тем как работать с незнакомым API, всегда лучше сперва ознакомиться с документацией :). Из MSDN про EmbeddedResources: "A collection that contains the **file paths** of .NET Framework resources to include in the generated assembly."

Comment: @andreycha, не хотелось лишний файл создавать, а так да, будет уроком)

Comment: Пометьте свой ответ как верный.

Answer (score 4):

Ошибка CS2032 означает недопустимый символ в параметрах компилятора. По всей видимости, ругается на это:

```
CompilerOptions = "/out:C:\\"
```

тут должен быть указан в т.ч. сам файл. Но по идее нет смысла возиться с ключом out, задавайте полный путь так:

```
OutputAssembly = "с:\\test.dll"
```